# SASS style two nested divs with no classes/

Tags: css, sass

I have the following html markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div> <------Want this to bee 100% height
    <div class="child">
    </div>

    <div class="child">
    </div>

    <div> < --------- 100% height
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the two classless divs to have a height of `100%`

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  > div {
    height: 100%;
  },
  > div > div {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

This works, but how do I accomplish this in a single rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `:not` pseudo selector to exclude any element with a class.

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  div:not([class]) {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

This will essentially select any `div` that does not have a class attribute set.

Here's an example with the SASS above compiled to CSS.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container div:not([class]) {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.container div.child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    jkfhakfhkadshfksdhfasdk
    <div class="child">

      child
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      dhild
    </div>

    <div>
      djalfjasdl;fjasl;fjas;lfj
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If you only want to go two levels deep (meaning classes `divs` won't be affected within the second level div), you can do this:

```
.container {
  height: 100%;

  > div:not([class]) {
    height: 100%;

    > div:not([class]) {
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is in action with the second level selector:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container .child {
  background: blue;
}

.container>div:not([class]) {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.container>div:not([class])>div:not([class]) {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    top level no class
    <div class="child">

      first child with class
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      first child with class
    </div>

    <div>
      second child no class
      <div class="child">
        third child with class
        <div>
          fourth child no class no affected by red bg
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dcmh5sga/

Comment: This looks good, but there are a bunch of other nested divs, and there could possibly be classless ones in there somewhere, so isn't this dangerous?

Comment: This answer is based on your original question and markup. You need to be more specific if there are other variables at play. _I have the following html markup:_ leads us to believe that's what you are working with.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another snippet going two levels deep with classes divs and selectors

Comment: That makes the code very similar to what I already had, I was trying to avoid that kind of code repetition. But both those options are better than what I have now so will accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the code you have now is a little more verbose, as you can skip that whole second `div > div {...}` by using more nesting. Either way, there's not much else you can do with your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be a singe rule, you can do this:

```css
.container, .container > div, .container > div > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You could also apply the rule to all child divs, if that works for your case:

```css
.container, .container div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yes, indeed the child element css rule. I don't know if he would need the parent (.container)  but the 2nd example I would try would using the child css call only (.container div).

Comment: Yes, it's unclear if the `.container` part is necessary. Based on the SASS rule in the question, it is needed.